# sum function in master detail join query ... in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, sum

I have two table master detail , policy_master and POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL ... i need to join both on  conman column , policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER , 
and need sum of columns .. 
sum(POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.G_PREMIUM) as "Total Gross",
sum(POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.Net_PREMIUM) as "Total Net Premium"

I'm trying this

```
select 
  policy_master.C_CLIENT_NAME, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_TYPE, 
  policy_master.policy_refer, 
  policy_master.POLICY_CLASS, 
  policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT, 
  policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE, 
  policy_master.C_EXPIRY_DATE, 
  sum(
    POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.G_PREMIUM
  ) as "Total Gross", 
  sum(
    POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.Net_PERMIUM
  ) as "Total Net Premium" 
from 
  POLICY_MASTER, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL 
where 
  policy_master.policy_refer = POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.POLICY_REFER 
  and POLICY_MASTER.STATUS = 'Renewal Due' 
group by 
  POLICY_MASTER.policy_refer, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_NAME, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_BRANCH, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.policy_number, 
  policy_master.policy_refer, 
  policy_master.C_EXPIRY_DATE, 
  policy_master.C_CLIENT_NAME, 
  policy_master.POLICY_CLASS, 
  policy_master.POLICY_PRODUCT, 
  policy_master.P_ISSUE_DATE, 
  policy_master.STATUS, 
  POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL.INSURER_TYPE 
order by 
  policy_master.C_EXPIRY_DATE, 
  policy_master.policy_refer;
```

....

but the sum function is not working where one policy_master against two `POLICY_INSURER_DETAIL` entries

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? you have an error? wrong results? ....

Comment: sample data and expected&actual output will help here

Comment: Gsalem@ wrong result...

Comment: actual qurey output            
C_CLIENT_NAME INSURER_NAME INSURER_BRANCH POLICY_NUMBER INSURER_TYPE POLICY_REFER POLICY_CLASS POLICY_PRODUCT P_ISSUE_DATE C_EXPIRY_DATE Total Gross Total Net Premium
Amir Khan EFU General Insurance Ltd. Central Division 45234242 Leader 19-12-P-D-MTR-CVC-0031 Motor Commercial Vehicles Comprehensive 12-Dec-19 12-Dec-19 1200 1508
Amir Khan TPL General Insurance Main Branch 56756756 Follower 19-12-P-D-MTR-CVC-0031 Motor Commercial Vehicles Comprehensive 12-Dec-19 12-Dec-19 800 952

Comment: expected result           
C_CLIENT_NAME INSURER_NAME INSURER_BRANCH POLICY_NUMBER INSURER_TYPE POLICY_REFER POLICY_CLASS POLICY_PRODUCT P_ISSUE_DATE C_EXPIRY_DATE Total Gross Total Net Premium
Ajaz Sarwar EFU General Insurance Ltd. Central Division 43546446 Leader 19-12-P-C-MTR-CVC-0029 Motor Commercial Vehicles Comprehensive 12-Dec-19 19-Dec-20 600 754
Ajaz Sarwar TPL General Insurance Main Branch 53452423 Follower 19-12-P-C-MTR-CVC-0029 Motor Commercial Vehicles Comprehensive 12-Dec-19 19-Dec-20 400 476